# Laravel 5.4 joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm quite lost here. I am trying to get the list of people who are on the **Records** table which ***aren't*** on the **Profiles** tables which has the specific *course* (e.g Psychology) and *year* (e.g 2011). So far, this is what I came up with and unfortunately it's not working.

```
$check = Record::join('Profiles', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Records.firstname', '!=', 'Profiles.firstname');
        $join->on('Records.lastname', '!=', 'Profiles.lastname');
        $join->on('Records.middlename', '!=', 'Profiles.middlename');
    })
    ->select('Records.*', 'Profiles.*')
    ->where('Records.year', '2011')
    ->where('Records.course', 'Psychology')
    ->get(); 

    dump($check);
```

Is there any way that I can go around about this? I'm new to this. Thanks in advance. Advises and tips on joining tables would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

$check = \DB::table('Records')
            ->whereNotExists(function(Builder $query) {
                $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('Profiles')
                    ->whereRaw('Records.firstname = Profiles.firstname')
                    ->whereRaw('Records.middlename = Profiles.middlename')
                    ->whereRaw('Records.lastname = Profiles.lastname');
            })
            ->select('firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname')
            ->where('year', 2011)
            ->where('course', 'Psychology');
            ->get();
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for helping. Your solution gives me an error but I fixed it by removing 'Builder'. Now, the results are kinda weird. It's giving me all the list even if it's not in 2011. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Ah, the where conditions must be applied to the Records query. Will correct when I'm at a Computer again

Comment: Please try again now.

Comment: Oh it's working now, Thanks. But hmm, still gives me wrong results. It gives me all records even if they're in the Profile table. Was hoping to only get the records who aren't on the profile table.

Comment: Shouldn't start drinking this early. Now, last try!

Comment: Here's a toast for a working code! Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at doing a left outer join and then selecting the records that have a null profile name.

```
$check = Record::leftJoin('Profiles', function ($join) {
        $join->on('Records.firstname', '=', 'Profiles.firstname');
        $join->on('Records.lastname', '=', 'Profiles.lastname');
        $join->on('Records.middlename', '=', 'Profiles.middlename');
    })
    ->select('Records.*', 'Profiles.*')
    ->where('Records.year', '2011')
    ->where('Records.course', 'Psychology')
    ->whereNull('Profiles.firstname')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Think you're almost there but hmm the code is working but it's gives me an empty array.